# How to update Select Options value dynamically using ant design frame work

Tags: reactjs, antd, ant-design-pro

I have a combo box where I have multiple options like Executing, Suspended, Blocked and etc.. user can select any one of them, but by default there is one option called 'Executing' already selected

When server stars, data is coming from the backend lets say example Blocked,
I am trying to update default value from Executing to Blocked, so that user can under what server is sending.

```
<Select size={"small"} className="mission-status">
                                <Option value="Executing">{missionStatusConts.MISSION_STATUS.EXECUTING}</Option>
                                <Option value="Completed">{missionStatusConts.MISSION_STATUS.COMPLETED}</Option>
                                <Option value="Blocked">{missionStatusConts.MISSION_STATUS.BLOCKED}</Option>
                                <Option value="Waiting">{missionStatusConts.MISSION_STATUS.WAITING}</Option>
                                <Option value="Offline">{missionStatusConts.MISSION_STATUS.OFFLINE}</Option>
                                <Option value="AllStop">{missionStatusConts.MISSION_STATUS.ALLSTOP}</Option>
                            </Select>
```

Attached image for reference

[image]

Looking for quick help, i spend almost one day in antd frame work to make it done, i could not get it..

Appreciate help

Comment: please give us more details or post an answer if you've found an ideal solution.

Answer (score 2):

`Select` tag of `antd` has a property named `defaultValue`, which can be used to show initial value.
If you want to show 2nd option, then code will be:

```
<Select defaultValue='Completed' size={"small"} className="mission-status">
    <Option value="Executing">{missionStatusConts.MISSION_STATUS.EXECUTING}</Option>
    <Option value="Completed">{missionStatusConts.MISSION_STATUS.COMPLETED}</Option>
    <Option value="Blocked">{missionStatusConts.MISSION_STATUS.BLOCKED}</Option>
    <Option value="Waiting">{missionStatusConts.MISSION_STATUS.WAITING}</Option>
    <Option value="Offline">{missionStatusConts.MISSION_STATUS.OFFLINE}</Option>
    <Option value="AllStop">{missionStatusConts.MISSION_STATUS.ALLSTOP}</Option>
</Select>
```

For your reference: [Antd select api](https://ant.design/components/select/#API)

Answer (score 2):

Piggy backing off of [shibashis](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11073769/shibashis) answer, to make this a dynamic selector and to have a blank default, you'd have something like this:

```
<Select size={"small"} className="mission-status" defaultValue={undefined || null || ''}>
    {Object.keys(missionStatusConts.MISSION_STATUS).map(status =>
        (<Option value={status}>{status}</Option>)}
</Select>
```